# Cannot install florence

Tags: keyboard

I'm no expert on this at all but I was trying to set up a pop up keyboard and have tried the matchbox keyboard which is fine, but I'm told florence keyboard pops up automatically.
I'm using a raspberry pi4 with raspbian os.
Started here...
https://howtoraspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-virtual-keyboard/
But florence is not availabe when using 'sudo apt install florence'.
So went here...
http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/install.html
and did this...

$ tar -xjvf florence-0.6.2.tar.bz2

$ cd florence-0.6.2

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr

$ make

$ su -c "make install"
(I am so noob, I could not get that to show as code, I have no hope)

Anyway, I then get the error...
*configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.23 or later.*

But I have the latest one!  in fact it is newer than 0.23.

My /etc/apt/sources.list shows...
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi

How to install florence onto my pi4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On-screen keyboards don't "pop up automatically", instead, they hide themselves automatically when your focus is not in a text input field. You still have to run your keyboard manually or via your window manager's autorun script.

Florence package seems to have [build issues](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/florence) in Bullseye. It seems to be available in [Sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/florence) though.

Even if `apt` won't work, you can still try to install `florence` by manually downloading the *.deb package from http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/florence/, installing it with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and then running `sudo apt -f install` to get the missing dependencies. No idea if it will work though, considering the reported issues.

Another option is to install a different keyboard which supports auto-hide. I heard `onboard` does support it, though I never tried it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers.  I am currently looking at onboard.  got that installed and am currently finding ways for it to 'pop up' or 'auto hide'.

Answer (score 2):

`florence` is available through the apt package repository. You can verify this as follows:

```
$ apt-cache search florence
florence - extensible and scalable virtual keyboard for X
libflorence-1.0-1 - extensible and scalable virtual keyboard for X
libflorence-1.0-dev - extensible and scalable virtual keyboard for X
qsapecng - symbolic analyzer and solver of linear analog circuits
```

I don't know why it won't install on your system - `apt` says it will install on mine - I bailed out at the `yes/no` question as I don't need it:

```
$ sudo apt update  # always before a new install
...
$ sudo apt install florence
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libcairo-gobject2
  libcolord2 libdconf1 libepoxy0 libflorence-1.0-1 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
  liblcms2-2 libnotify4 libproxy1v5 librest-0.7-0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libxcomposite1
  libxcursor1 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 notification-daemon
Suggested packages:
  colord gstreamer1.0-tools gvfs liblcms2-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service florence glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libcairo-gobject2
  libcolord2 libdconf1 libepoxy0 libflorence-1.0-1 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
  liblcms2-2 libnotify4 libproxy1v5 librest-0.7-0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libxcomposite1
  libxcursor1 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 notification-daemon
0 upgraded, 41 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 80.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
$
```

I wonder if the tarball you downloaded was for `arm` architecture - or something else?

#### Addendum:

May 5, 2022: The `florence` package appears to have been pulled since I checked it yesterday. Today's `apt-cache search` yields:

```bsh
$ apt-cache search florence
texlive-publishers - TeX Live: Publisher styles, theses, etc.
```

Strange business! The `florence` .deb package [still appears in the repository here.](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/florence/)

Comment: '''simon@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install florence
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package florence
simon@raspberrypi:~ $'''

Comment: @styleruk: Maybe check the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`? And I don't know why you're going to Debian's repo???

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing to be honest.  I went there to see if the package exists and it's not listed so I assume I cannot get it for my level of OS.

Comment: Seamus; Is there another source I can add to the sources.list to get florence?

Comment: from the archive repository, is there a way to a)add that to my sources or b) install from the *.debian.tar.xz.  I downloaded that but I do not know how to install that correctly

Comment: I have tried dpkg --install but they are not debian format archives.

Comment: @styleruk: AFAIK, packages don't come and go on their own, so I can only guess the RPi Organization has removed `florence` - but they didn't do a complete job as it remains [in the repo](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/florence/). I was about to suggest you try the same approach provided in Dmitry's answer. If you're still keen of `florence` you can try that. The other approach is installing the source files & building it on your system. [Here's an exampleshowing how I did that.](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FixDhcpcd.md)

Comment: @styleruk said `"but they are not debian format archives."`  How did you come to that conclusion?